# Where is jquery coming from?? (Rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to debug a jquery plugin in Ruby on Rails that requires jquery.

I installed jquery via yarn and require it in application.js... but the debugging search led me to believe that I have jquery loaded multiple times and indeed - EVEN if I remove the "require..." statement from application.js, $().jquery still results in 1.6. when typing it into the console...

I looked everywhere and I simply can't figure out where jquery is coming from, so is there a (definitive and finite) list of places it could be loaded from?

EDIT: I did a yarn list AFTER I removed jquery with yarn remove jquery (and indeed it is still no longer in package.json), BUT it is still listed (and the subfolder for jquery is still in node_modules). I do have the jquery initialisation code still in config/webpack/environment.js, and ONLY when I remove this code, jquery is no longer there. So in a nutshell it seems:

- jQuery is part of node modules even though i removed with yarn remove (?)
- jquery can be initialized thus in environment.js
- jquery does NOT need to be required in application.js

I have to say this is way over my head.... any help appreciated. THe one thing I am trying to solve is: I import a jquery plugin called easy-autocomplete (works like charm), and then I also try to import selectize, but I get an error message "selectize() is not defined"...

Content of environment.js:

```
const { environment } = require("@rails/webpacker");

const webpack = require("webpack");
environment.plugins.prepend(
  "Provide",
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery/src/jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery/src/jquery",
  })
);

module.exports = environment;
```

EDIT: package.json after removing jquery:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.3",
    "easy-autocomplete": "^1.3.5",
    "selectize": "^0.12.6",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3"
  }
}
```

Gemfile (comments removed):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.0'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.1'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

gem 'pagy'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'open-uri'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'spring'

  gem 'htmlbeautifier'
  gem 'solargraph'
  gem 'rubocop'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

.

Comment: Are you using sprockets or webpack? Webpack is now the default I believe. Also, which version of rails?

Comment: Ah sorry forgot. Yes webpack, and Rails  6.1.4.1

Comment: It would really either be the Gemfile or package.json afaik. It's _possible_ the jquery you're seeing is coming from an extension on your browser or something, I would check in incognito mode to make sure you're experiencing the same thing there.

Comment: It's in package.json, but i didn't include it into my application.js... so how would it be loaded? That's what puzzles me...

Comment: Well does removing it from the package.json fix the issue? It's possible Rails does some sort of "magic" there and includes it automatically. Those devs love magic.

Comment: ok that is super weird. I removed jquery (yarn remove jquery), so no longer in package.json - I posted the content of package.json in the original question. STILL - $().jquery results in 3.6.0 when I type it in the console??? (I also posted the gemfile, just to be on the safe side :)

Comment: Looks like rack_mini_profiler may use jquery for some of its features. My first try would be disabling that or running rails in an environment other than development. Otherwise it's really going through all of your dependencies and checking what may be using jquery, it's coming from somewhere.